# Disabled TextArea Resize stops working when there is Overflow-Y

Tags: html, css, textarea

If a textarea is disabled and has overflow-y it no longer lets you resize.
If you add overflow-y to hidden and keep it disabled it does let you resize.

Any way to have a disabled textarea with scrollable overflow-y and still have it resizable?

Fiddle with just textarea: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bs5sakus/ (not resizable)

```
<textarea disabled> TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST </textarea>
```

Fiddle with overflow-y hidden: https://jsfiddle.net/30o3tmap/ (resizable)

Comment: `<textarea>` does not have that problem [**by default**](https://jsfiddle.net/n41edwym/). Something in your application is causing it to break. Please isolate the problem, adding just enough code to showcase the problem in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Because you have not included enough code in your question to replicate the problem, it is currently literally impossible for any of us to debug this for you.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yo homegir! I updated it with a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Hook me up with some workarounds plz&thx :)

Comment: Well I'm not a girl, but now that you've updated your question it does clearly show a problem. You should be able to add `overflow-y: scroll` and `resize: both` to the element, but that doesn't seem to work if it's disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is to use readonly instead of disabled and style it to look disabled. This also allows users to highlight and copy the text in the textarea but not modify it

https://jsfiddle.net/xynLfqag/1/

```
<textarea readonly> TEST </textarea>
```

jQuery UI resizable will work but using the SE grabber and scrollbars cause overlapping

[image]

https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 0):

Hello I ran into the same situation here.
As I read in some comments above, the issue may be with your own app as the default behaviour does allow the scroll and resize simultaneously

In my case, I found somewhere forgotten in my app the following css set up:

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
}
```

This was avoiding the correct default behavour from `textarea`
I removed it and the `textarea` worked as expected
Hope it helps